# how to make fake cursor in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>

    <style type="text/css">
#fake /* fake cursor */
{
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
}



</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#div1').ready(function() {

  $('#div1').bind('mousemove', function(e){
  $('#fake').css({
     left:  e.pageX + 200,
     top:   e.pageY
  });
  });


});


</script>

</head>
<body style="cursor:text;">


<div id="div1" style="height:300px;width:300px;border:1px solid red;"></div>


  <div id="fake" ><img id="cursor" src="xp.png" /></div><br />

<body>

</html>
```

i want to hide the fake cursor when mouse cursor is out of div1.how can i do this.i tried using this code below but it dint work.please help.and any suggestions over shouldersurfing are most welcomed.

```
$("#div1").mouseout(function () {
$("#fake").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jquery's .on statement instead of your separate mousemove and mouseout events:

```
 $("#div1").on({
        mousemove: function () {
            $('#fake').css({
                left: e.pageX + 200,
                top: e.pageY
            });
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $("#fake").hide();
            alert("Mouse Out!")
        }
    });
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYksu/)